# Where does one normally save non business logic data?

Tags: database-design

Hi I'm trying to measure how long an end to end request takes to complete.

I'm using the facebook realtime api to receive callbacks to my box. Basically a user checks-in to a location and I get a callback. I'd like to measure the total time of that entire scenario(from checkin to callback received).

My current plan is to use the timestamp that arrives with the callback and compare it with the time on the box and use that as a measurement and put it into my mysql database.

My question is where does one usually save data that dosen't really have to do with the business logic of the application in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking a generic product design - where you have business logic processing data and non-business logic processing data - then from my experience, we create two set of data holder - 1 Service data store (you can read as business logic data) and 2 Non service meta data store (you can read as non-business logic data).

1. Now as to question of where to exactly store, It depends on your application. Many a times, in distributed system, these data needs to be shared among different agent entities which act as a localized servers. In such scenario - you would store them in another db file.
2. In case it is a localized data (may be for example app), then may be dual data base - one for localized information rendering and one (service database) for data sharing would be better approach.

Basically the intent, amount of data would be two major criteria to choose the data store.